# SQL: Sum factor*value in a LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join

I would like to get some information: I got a table called "invoices" and a table called "invoice_positions".

All personal information about a customer are stored in "invoices". All positions are stored in "invoice_positions".

Well, now I would like to know the total sum of all matching positions:

I got this invoice-entry:

id: 1
customer: 4

I got this invoice-positions-entry:

```
id: 1
invoiceid: 1
factor: 2
value: 5

id: 2
invoiceid: 1
factor: 1
value: 5
```

The result should be: `2*5+1*5 = 15`

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*,SUM(ip.factor * ip.value) as totalsum,om.orderid,o.userid as userid,c.lastname as customer_lastname, c.firstname as customer_firstname, c.company as customer_company,uc.name AS editor,created_by.name AS created_by 
FROM `o45_hero_invoices` AS a 
LEFT JOIN o45_hero_invoices_positions AS ip ON ip.invoiceid=a.id 
LEFT JOIN o45_hero_invoices_mapping AS om ON om.invoiceid=a.id 
LEFT JOIN o45_hero_orders AS o ON o.id=om.orderid 
LEFT JOIN o45_hero_customers AS c ON c.userid=o.userid 
LEFT JOIN o45_users AS uc ON uc.id=a.checked_out 
LEFT JOIN o45_users AS created_by ON created_by.id = a.created_by 
WHERE (a.state IN (0, 1)) 
ORDER BY a.id asc
```

But my result is not 15 - it's 30.

Comment: Do you have a group by in there?

Comment: Yeah, SUM() is an aggregate function. With no GROUP BY clause, it won't work the way you want.

Comment: Hey there and thank you for your answers. I updated the initial question - now you can see the whole query. Which field should I use to group?

Comment: all those left joins. Are they one-to-one relationships between each table or is there an additional one to many outside of the invoice_positions to invoices?  if you have more than that it will impact your results.  As far as group by.... all the fields which are not part of the aggregrate you have listed in the select.  mySQL extends the group by to allow this type of logic.  However it is free to choose ANY value in the series and display it allowing a performance boost.  This works fine so long as all the values are the same, but if you have any differences... you'll have improper results.

Comment: Hey there,

they are all one-to-one-related.

Answer (score 0):

1. you will no longer need the distinct with the group by.
2. a.* will have to be split into individual columns you want to return in results.
3. group by has been added below for known columns

.

```
SELECT a.*,SUM(ip.factor * ip.value) as totalsum,
  om.orderid, o.userid as userid, c.lastname as customer_lastname, 
  c.firstname as customer_firstname, c.company as customer_company,
  uc.name AS editor,
  created_by.name AS created_by 
FROM `o45_hero_invoices` AS a 
LEFT JOIN o45_hero_invoices_positions AS ip ON ip.invoiceid=a.id 
LEFT JOIN o45_hero_invoices_mapping AS om ON om.invoiceid=a.id 
LEFT JOIN o45_hero_orders AS o ON o.id=om.orderid 
LEFT JOIN o45_hero_customers AS c ON c.userid=o.userid 
LEFT JOIN o45_users AS uc ON uc.id=a.checked_out 
LEFT JOIN o45_users AS created_by ON created_by.id = a.created_by 
WHERE (a.state IN (0, 1)) 
GROUP BY a.Field1, a.Field2, A.Field3...,
  om.orderid, o.userid, c.lastname, c.firstname, 
  c.company, uc.name, created_by.name 
ORDER BY a.id asc
```